# How Do I pass an image source to a variable in a function to be then shown to a image tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I have an Image gallery that has three images, I created a thumbnail for the three images and if ever I click on a thumbnail i want it to show on my main image tag.

This is my main image tag:

```
<img style="width: 100%;" ng-model="" id="viewpic" name="viewpic" src="something.jpg" >
```

This is my thumbnails:

```
<img style="width: 28%;" src="images/terminus_63_img3.jpg" onClick="functionshow();">
<img style="width: 28%;" src="images/terminus_63_img3.jpg" onClick="functionshow();">
<img style="width: 28%;" src="images/terminus_63_img3.jpg" onClick="functionshow();">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img style="width: 100%;" id="viewpic" name="viewpic" ng-src="viewpic" >

<img style="width: 28%;" src="images/terminus_63_img3.jpg" ng-click="functionshow('images/terminus_63_img3.jpg');">
<img style="width: 28%;" src="images/terminus_63_img3.jpg" ng-click="functionshow('images/terminus_63_img3.jpg');">
<img style="width: 28%;" src="images/terminus_63_img3.jpg" ng-click="functionshow('images/terminus_63_img3.jpg');">
```

in your controller

```
$scope.functionshow = function (src) {
$scope.viewpic = src;
};
```

Comment: I have a controller, what i did is  vm.functionshow=function(scr){console.log('ping');var viewpic = scr;}; but my function seems to not be running...

Comment: can you share a plnkr link?

Comment: I got it running, but instead of using scope, i used var vm in my controller.

Comment: cool :) yeah controllerAs is always a good way to write angular controller than use $scope. This makes your controller independent of any framework. :)